# Multiple ResourceBundles with Spring and JSTL

Tags: spring, jstl, tiles, resourcebundle

Here's my problem: I want to organize my resource bundle files so that I have the messages in one file and the labels in another. For this I created two .properties files which I declared in my spring configuration files. The actual declaration is this:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <array>
            <value>strings.gui</value>
            <value>strings.messages</value>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The folder layout goes like this:

**/WEB-INF/classes/ro/**** - source files

**/WEB-INF/classes/strings/*** - i18n files (gui_ro.properties and messages_ro.properties, along with their _en versions)

Everything works great when I display labels from **gui_xx.properties** but it fails to display messages from **messages_xx.properties** files. The error message in the server console is

```
ResourceBundle [strings.messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name strings.messages, locale ro
```

I'm using JSTL with TilesView, and the problem occurs regardless of what tag I use to display the text - **fmt:message key=...** or **spring:message code=...**.

Can anybody help pe with this?

Thank you very much and have a good day.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the same error occurs when I try to access the messages from the controller code (i.e. using messageSource.getMessage() )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the correct basenames should be:

```
    <value>classpath:/ro/gui</value>
    <value>classpath:/strings/messages</value>
```

Can you please try these values for basenames.

Comment: That did the trick. I tried using _classpath_ before, but I forgot the preceding / and it didn't work. Thank you very much!